# Prevent CSS Hover Transition on mouseup

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have created a button using CSS in which the background color fades lighter on mouseover and immediately becomes darker on mousedown. The problem is that I want to maintain the button's hover state on mouseup without repeating its transition. How can that be done?

```css
.btn1 {
    background-color: #08f;
    border-top: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #048;
    border-left: 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16pt;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
}
.btn1:hover {
    background-color: #0cf;
}
.btn1:active {
    background-color: #048;
    border-top: 3px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 0;
    color: #888;
    transition: background-color 0s;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <button class="btn1">Button</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Your later part is confusing me ! Whatever is the buttons effect on **mouse-down**, you want it to stay even after user clicks and does **mouse-up** ?
If so, just try adding `:active` property to `:focus` as well, `.btn1:active,.btn1:focus {properties}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the active property with an animation set to forwards

```css
.btn1 {
    background-color: #08f;
    border-top: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #048;
    border-left: 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16pt;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
}
.btn1:hover {
    background-color: #0cf;
}
.btn1:active {
    border-top: 3px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 0;
    color: #888;
    animation: activate 0.1s forwards;
}

@keyframes activate {
    from {background-color: #0cf;}  
    to {background-color: #048;}  
}
```

```html
<body>
    <button class="btn1">Button</button>
</body>
```

Comment: It worked once I changed 0.1s to 0s after `animation`. Thanks!